# not able to get first inserted rows identity in cursor loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor, temporary

I have been trying inserting some rows into a temporary table which required identity from table A ...this A table is being inserted from a cursor..
everything is working fine here but only the problem i am getting is that i don't get identity  of first inserted row in table A
suppose i insert 3 rows in table A ...i get last 2 rows in temporary table ..not first one..and if i send just one row in table A then temporary table is blank
here is my stored procedure ..table A is tblClients

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[lsp1_propAdmClnt]          
(          
@usrprflId bigint,          
@preClient tpClient readonly           

)          
as            
declare @err int         
CREATE TABLE #tblids(      
clntid int,      
imgname nvarchar(350)  

)  
declare @clntid as int      
declare @clntname nvarchar(300)      
declare @imgname nvarchar(300)     
Begin Transaction        




declare transfclntid cursor for select  clntname, [imgname] from @preClient      
open transfclntid      
fetch next from transfclntid into @clntname, @imgname      
while @@fetch_status=0      
begin      

insert into tblClients (usrprflId,Name,Img,cdate) 
values(@usrprflId, @clntname, @imgname,GETDATE())      

SET @clntid = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())    
insert into #tblids (clntid, imgname) values (@clntid, @imgname)      
fetch next from transfclntid into @clntname, @imgname      
end      
close transfclntid      
deallocate transfclntid      


 select * from  #tblids                        
select @err=@@TOTAL_ERRORS          
if(@err<>0)          
Begin          
Rollback Transaction          
return 0          
End          

Commit transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should replace that cursor with following `INSERT SELECT` statement:

```
declare @tblids table
(
    clntid INT NOT NULL,
    imgname NVARCHAR(350)
);
insert into tblClients (usrprflId, Name, Img, cdate) 
output inserted.clntid, inserted.Img into @tblids (clntid, imgname)
select  @usrprflId, clntname, [imgname], GETDATE()
from @preClient
```

Then if you need the first identity value you could use:

```
SELECT MIN(clntid)
FROM @tblids
```